# How to convert a "char number" into an int WITHOUT use of magic numbers? (in C++)

Tags: c++, char, int

In other words, based on the ASCII table, from the range of '0' to '9',

how may I convert them into integers 0 to 9?

A solution such as:

```
char a = '6';
int b = a-48;
```

has already been floating around these parts, but I was wondering if there are other ways to go about this without the use of **magic numbers**?

Comment: How about using `strtol`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `'0'` is not guaranteed to be `48`, but the numbers are guaranteed to be consecutive, you can use `a-'0'`.

Comment: This is actually for a homework assignment but do you think stylistically it would be acceptable? Obviously you're not in the class but amongst, idk, industry standards, do you think it would be OK?

Comment: @HelloMyNameIsRay I for one think it's fine, alternatively you could use a `switch` statement or `std::stringstream` to do the conversion for you.

Comment: @HelloMyNameIsRay: it's certainly common to write it that way. For pretty much anything you can find *someone* who'd prefer to do it differently.

Comment: @jrok: Since `'0'` clearly expresses the intent, I wouldn't call it a magic number.

Comment: Thanks, all! i double checked with my professor and within the scope of this class, this is the acceptable method

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you could use a `stringstream` like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int charToInt(char c) {

  // initialize a buffered stream with a 1-character string
  std::stringstream ss(std::string(1,c));

  // read an int from the stream
  int v;
  ss >> v;
  return v;

}
```

Not the simplest way to do the conversion, but this way you don't see any of the implementation details involving "magic" number or character. You also get error handling (an exception is thrown) if the caracter was not a number.

On the other hand, if you're absolutely certain that the character `c` is in the `'0'..'9'` range, I don't see why not use `c - '0'`.

Another solution is to replace `c - 48` with `c & 0xf`, but that still involves magic numbers and is less readable than `c - '0'`

Comment: Even if the platform uses a non-ASCII character set, if the digits in that character set are not consecutive starting from `'0'` then it's not C++. It's a requirement on the execution charset.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I didn't know that, any source? But even if it's ordered you have an issue when cross-compiling because `'0'` in the source file could be interpreted as ascii 48 and not the target codepoint.

Comment: Source is the standard, [lex.charset] "The value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous". There's no problem when cross-compiling because of the difference between the source character set and the execution character set [lex.phases], "Each source character set member ... is converted to a member of the execution character set". So `'0'` *always* means the value of digit `0` in the execution set. You'd have a problem if the source was mis-interpreted with the wrong encoding, of course.

Comment: @SteveJessop: ok thanks for this info - I removed the non ascii usecase from my post.

Answer (score 1):

The ascii table is ordered in an hexadecimal way, so it's very easy to change numbers characters to real number value, or another things like to Uppercase to Lower...

As the numbers begin in the 0x30, then 0x30 =0 , 0x31 = 1, 0x32 =2, etc, you must just remove the 0x30 to get the real value.

```
char number='2';
int numberValue = (int)number - 0x30; /* you can rest the '0' value too */
```

As it, to convert an int to char is the same, just add it the 0x30.

```
int numberValue=5;
char number = (int)numberValue +0x30; /* or add '0' to your var */
```

Comment: A more symbolic and easier to read method is to subtract `0` from the character.  This is more portable across different character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract ASCII zero from the number:

```
char a = '2';
int b = a-'0';
```

If you can't use '0', how about that kind of cheating?

```
(int)(a + 2) % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a char, not a char pointer, you can do this:

```
 int convert (char x)
 {
     return (int(x) - int('0'));
 }
```

Comment: Are the casts necessary?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No, the casts are not necessary.